# Reinforcement learning algorithm using turtle graphics not functioning

Tags: python, algorithm, turtle-graphics, reinforcement-learning

Currently trying to implement a Q table algorithm in my environment created using turtle graphics. When i try running the algorithm which uses Q learning I get an error stating:

```
  File "<ipython-input-1-cf5669494f75>", line 304, in <module>
    rl()

  File "<ipython-input-1-cf5669494f75>", line 282, in rl
    A = choose_action(S, q_table)

  File "<ipython-input-1-cf5669494f75>", line 162, in choose_action
    state_actions = q_table.iloc[state, :]

  File "/Users/himansuodedra/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1367, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)

  File "/Users/himansuodedra/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1737, in _getitem_tuple
    self._has_valid_tuple(tup)

  File "/Users/himansuodedra/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 204, in _has_valid_tuple
    if not self._has_valid_type(k, i):

  File "/Users/himansuodedra/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1674, in _has_valid_type
    return self._is_valid_list_like(key, axis)

  File "/Users/himansuodedra/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1723, in _is_valid_list_like
    raise IndexingError('Too many indexers')

IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

I cannot seem to pinpoint the problem. The logic to me looks fine. Also I am able to build the environment thereafter the script gets stuck and i am forced to terminate it. Any help would be great. The code is below:

```
"""
Reinforcement Learning using table lookup Q-learning method.
An agent "Blue circle" is positioned in a grid and must make its way to the 
green square. This is the end goal. Each time the agent should improve its 
strategy to reach the final Square. There are two traps the red and the wall 
which will reset the agent. 
"""
import turtle
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

np.random.seed(2)

""" Setting Parameters """

#N_STATES = 12   # the size of the 2D world
ACTIONS = ['left', 'right', 'down','up']     # available actions
EPSILON = 0.9   # greedy police (randomness factor)
ALPHA = 0.1     # learning rate 
GAMMA = 0.9    # discount factor
MAX_EPISODES = 13   # maximum episodes
FRESH_TIME = 0.3    # fresh time for one move


def isGoal():
    if player.xcor() == -25 and player.ycor() == 225:
        player.goto(-175,125)
        status_func(1)
        S_ = 'terminal'
        R = 1
        interaction = 'Episode %s: total_steps = %s' %(episode+1, step_counter)
        print('\r{}'.format(interaction), end='')
        time.sleep(2)
        print('\r', end='')
        return S_, R
    else:
        pass


def isFire():
    if player.xcor() == -25 and player.ycor() == 175:
        player.goto(-175,125)
        status_func(3)
        S_ = 'terminal'
        R = -1
        interaction = 'Episode %s: total_steps = %s' %(episode+1, step_counter)
        print('\r{}'.format(interaction), end='')
        time.sleep(2)
        print('\r', end='')
        return S_, R
    else:
        pass 


def isWall():
    if player.xcor() == -125 and player.ycor() == 175:
        player.goto(-175,125)
        status_func(2)
        S_ = 'terminal'
        R = -1
        interaction = 'Episode %s: total_steps = %s' %(episode+1, step_counter)
        print('\r{}'.format(interaction), end='')
        time.sleep(2)
        print('\r', end='')
        return S_, R
    else:
        pass


""" Player Movement """

playerspeed = 50

""" Create the token object """

player = turtle.Turtle()
player.color("blue")
player.shape("circle")
player.penup()
player.speed(0)
player.setposition(-175,125)
player.setheading(90)



#Move the player left and right
def move_left():
    x = player.xcor()
    x -= playerspeed
    if x < -175:
        x = -175
    player.setx(x)
    isGoal()
    isFire()
    isWall()
    S_ = player.pos()
    R = 0

def move_right():
    x = player.xcor()
    x += playerspeed
    if x > -25:
        x = -25
    player.setx(x)
    isGoal()
    isFire()
    isWall()
    S_ = player.pos()
    R = 0

def move_up():
    y = player.ycor()
    y += playerspeed
    if y > 225:
        y = 225
    player.sety(y)
    isGoal()
    isFire()
    isWall()
    S_ = player.pos()
    R = 0

def move_down():
    y = player.ycor()
    y -= playerspeed
    if y < 125:
        y = 125
    player.sety(y)
    isGoal()
    isFire()
    isWall()
    S_ = player.pos()
    R = 0

#Create Keyboard Bindings
turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(move_left, "Left")
turtle.onkey(move_right, "Right")
turtle.onkey(move_up, "Up")
turtle.onkey(move_down, "Down")

def build_q_table(n_states, actions):
    table = pd.DataFrame(
        np.zeros((n_states, len(actions))),     # q_table initial values
        columns=actions,    # actions's name
    )
    # print(table)    # show table
    return table


def choose_action(state, q_table):
    # This is how to choose an action
    state_actions = q_table.iloc[state, :]
    # act non-greedy or state-action have no value
    if (np.random.uniform() > EPSILON) or ((state_actions == 0).all()): 
        action_name = np.random.choice(ACTIONS)
    else:   # act greedy
        # replace argmax to idxmax as argmax means a different function 
        action_name = state_actions.idxmax()    
    return action_name



def get_env_feedback(S, A):
    if A == 'right':
        move_right()
    elif A == 'left':
        move_left()
    elif A == 'up':
        move_up()
    else: #down 
        move_down()
    return S_, R



def update_env(S, episode, step_counter):
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    wn.bgcolor("white")
    wn.title("test")

    """ Create the Grid """

    greg = turtle.Turtle()
    greg.speed(0)

    def create_square(size,color="black"):
        greg.color(color)
        greg.pd()
        for i in range(4):
            greg.fd(size)
            greg.lt(90)
        greg.pu()
        greg.fd(size)

    def row(size,color="black"):
        for i in range(4):
            create_square(size)

    def board(size,color="black"):
        greg.pu()
        greg.goto(-(size*4),(size*4))
        for i in range(3):
            row(size)
            greg.bk(size*4)
            greg.rt(90)
            greg.fd(size)
            greg.lt(90)

    def color_square(start_pos,distance_sq, sq_width, color):
        greg.pu()
        greg.goto(start_pos)
        greg.fd(distance_sq)
        greg.color(color)
        greg.begin_fill()
        for i in range(4):
            greg.fd(sq_width)
            greg.lt(90)
        greg.end_fill()
        greg.pu()

    def initiate_grid(): 
        board(50)
        color_square((-200,200),150, 50,color="green")
        color_square((-200,150),50, 50,color="black")
        color_square((-200,150),150, 50,color="red")
        greg.hideturtle()

    initiate_grid()

    """ Create the token object """

    player = turtle.Turtle()
    player.color("blue")
    player.shape("circle")
    player.penup()
    player.speed(0)
    player.setposition(S)
    player.setheading(90)




def rl():
    possible_states = {0:(-175,125),
                      1:(-175,175),
                      2:(-175,225),
                      3:(-125,125),
                      4:(-125,175),
                      5:(-125,225),
                      6:(-75,125),
                      7:(-75,175),
                      8:(-75,225),
                      9:(-25,125),
                      10:(-25,175),
                      11:(-25,225)}

    inv_possible_states = {v:k for k,v in possible_states.items()}

    #build the qtable 
    q_table = build_q_table(len(possible_states),ACTIONS)
    for episode in range(MAX_EPISODES):
        step_counter = 0
        which_state = 0
        S = possible_states[which_state]
        is_terminated = False
        update_env(S,episode,step_counter)
        while not is_terminated:

            A = choose_action(S, q_table)
            # take action & get next state and reward
            S_, R = get_env_feedback(S, A) 
            q_predict = q_table.loc[S, A]
            if S_ != 'terminal':
                S_ = inv_possible_states[S_]
                # next state is not terminal
                q_target = R + GAMMA * q_table.iloc[S_, :].max()   
            else:
                q_target = R     # next state is terminal
                is_terminated = True    # terminate this episode

            q_table.loc[S, A] += ALPHA * (q_target - q_predict)  # update
            S = S_  # move to next state

            update_env(S, episode, step_counter+1)
            step_counter += 1
    return q_table



rl()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Short answer*: **You are confusing the screen coordinates with the 12 states of the environment**

*Long answer*: When `A = choose_action(S, q_table)` is called and the `choose_action` method is executed, you are running into problems with the following line of code within that method:

```
state_actions = q_table.iloc[state, :]
```

The error `IndexingError: Too many indexers` is trying to tell you that the value you're trying to access does not exist on the `q_table`.

If you were to print out the `state` variable that gets passed into the `choose_action` function, you'll get this:

```
(-175, 125)
```

But that doesn't make sense. If you print entire Q-table before the error happens, you'll see the following values:

```
    left  right  down   up
0    0.0    0.0   0.0  0.0
1    0.0    0.0   0.0  0.0
2    0.0    0.0   0.0  0.0
3    0.0    0.0   0.0  0.0
4    0.0    0.0   0.0  0.0
5    0.0    0.0   0.0  0.0
6    0.0    0.0   0.0  0.0
7    0.0    0.0   0.0  0.0
8    0.0    0.0   0.0  0.0
9    0.0    0.0   0.0  0.0
10   0.0    0.0   0.0  0.0
11   0.0    0.0   0.0  0.0
```

The values are all zeros because you haven't learned anything yet. But your code is trying to access `q_table.iloc[state, :]` when `state` is equal to `(-175, 125)`. *That doesn't make any sense!*

The value you're passing in to the `choose_action` method should correspond to one of the twelve states within the environment, represented in the `q_table` by the integers from 0 to 11.

It seems the problem is being caused from this line:

```
S = possible_states[which_state]
```

☝️ That line of code in the `rl` method is changing the value of `S` to be `(-175, 125)`. If `S` is supposed to represent which state of the environment the agent is in, then `S` should always be an integer between 0 and 11 (inclusively).

You need to make sure that you correctly separate the screen locations that `turtle-graphics` is drawing from the 12 states of the environment that the agent is exploring. `turtle-graphics` doesn't know how to draw the environment states as they are stored within `q_table`, and the `q_table` doesn't know which states in the environment are associated with the coordinates that `turtle-graphics` uses to draw the squares.

Comment: No idea if your answer  is correct, but +1 for reading that much code!

Comment: @ReblochonMasque It wasn't so bad -- once you've seen one Q-learning algorithm, you've seen them all. Most of that code is setting up the environment.